# angular material dialog box

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material dialog box. currently its open. but i do not know how it close using dialog box close button. i tried several times, but could not do it.
please check below code (part of code)

```
      constructor(private summaryService: SummaryService,public dialog: MatDialog) { }
  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialog, {
    });


  }

  closeDialog(){
    alert("test");
    this.dialog.close();
  }
```

openDialog() is working well. i have two problems in the colseDialog() function.
when i alert some text, error " _co.closeDialog is not a function".
other error display in my IDE "Property 'close' does not exist on type 'MatDialog'". can u give solution to close popup

Comment: `this.dialogRef.close();` and not `this.dialog.close();`

Comment: error showing "Property 'dialogRef' does not exist on type 'SummaryComponent'."
summarycomponent is the component name\

Answer (score 1):

Try making dialogRef global variable in main.component.ts

```
dialogRef : MatDialogRef<ConfirmationDialog>

constructor(private summaryService: SummaryService,public dialog: MatDialog) { }

openDialog(): void {
   dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialog, {
   });
}

closeDialog(){
   alert("test");
   this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Try following changes in your confirmationDialog.component.ts

```
constructor(
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ESignatureComponent>,
 ) { }

onCloseClick(){
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Comment: now no errors in text editor. but when i click close button in the dialogbox, error occurred in console, "ERROR TypeError: _co.closeDialog is not a function"

Comment: your close button is in dialogBox, so you have to call `this.dialogRef.close()` in your dialog component

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, you have to listen to the close event in the method where you declared your dialogRef object, otherwise it will be undefined.

```
openDialog(): void {
   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialog);
   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if(result) {
        //Means user clicked on OK button
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use afterOpened event to get modal Window globally.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  dialogRef: MatDialog;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document, public store: Store, dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.dialogRef = dialog;
    this.dialogRef.afterOpened.subscribe(value => {
      console.log("Some Modal Window Opened");
    })
  }
```